# C Struct with pointer to array

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code, and I'm a bit confused as to why I'm getting a segmentation fault.

```
typedef struct {
  int tag;
  int valid;
} Row;

typedef struct {
  int index;
  int num_rows;
  Row **rows;
} Set;

/* STRUCT CONSTRUCTORS */

// Returns a pointer to a new Sow.
// all fields of this row are NULL
Row* new_row() {
  Row* r = malloc(sizeof(Row));
  return r;
}

// Returns a pointer to a new Set.
// the set's index is the given index, and it has an array of
// rows of the given length.
Set* new_set( int index, int num_rows, int block_size ) {
  Set* s = malloc(sizeof(Set));
  s->index = index;
  s->num_rows = num_rows;

  Row* rows[num_rows];
  for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    Row* row_p = new_row();
    rows[i] = row_p;
  }
  s->rows = rows;

  return s;
}

/* PRINTING */

void print_row( Row* row ) {
  printf("<<T: %d, V: %d>>", row->tag, row->valid);
}

void print_set( Set* set ) {
  printf("[ INDEX %d :", set->index);


  for (int i = 0; i < set->num_rows; i++) {
    Row* row_p = set->rows[i];
    print_row(row_p);
  }

  printf(" ]\n");
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

  Set* s = new_set(1, 4, 8);
  print_set(s);


  return 0;

}
```

Basically a `Set` has a pointer to a array of `Row`s. I'd think `Row* row_p = set->rows[i];` would be the right way to get the row from a set, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating a local array of `Row*`s

```
  Row* rows[num_rows];
  for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
    Row* row_p = new_row();
    rows[i] = row_p;
  }
  s->rows = rows;
```

and let the `rows` pointer of the `Set` point to that. The local array doesn't exist anymore after the function returned, so `s->rows` is then a dangling pointer. Memory that shall still be valid after the function returned must be allocated with `malloc` (or one of its cousins).

Answer (score 1):

`s->rows` is assigned the address of the local variable `rows` in the function `new_set()`, which means `s->rows` is a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) when `new_set()` returns. Dynamically allocate an array of `Row*` to correct:

```
s->rows = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(Row*));
if (s->rows)
{
    /* for loop as is. */
}
```

Remember that `s->rows`, as well as its elements, must be `free()`d.